# Take h2 and add to next/previous buttons in tabbed interface

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which is basically trying to grab the h2 title and add it to my next and previous buttons:

```
 <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="2">Next</a>
 <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="0">Previous</a>
```

Each tab is structured like this:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>content here</p> 
    <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="1">Next</a>
</div>
```

Here's my jsfiddle, I just can't work out how to make it work, if I changed the rels to start from 1 instead of 0 it works great but we're using jquery ui which generates this automatically which means we're stuck with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/2/

Comment: Seems like using UI's built-in tabs functions would be simpler. Could you update your fiddle with the full tab structure?

Comment: You mean, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/4/?

Comment: isherwood here's the actual code without me trying to simplify it http://jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/7/

Comment: Karl-André Gagnon that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl-Andre answered above in the comments:

> You mean, like this : jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/4

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
     <h2>Title 1</h2>

    <p>content here</p> <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="1">Next</a>

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
     <h2>Title 2</h2>

    <p>content here</p> <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="2">Next</a>
 <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="0">Previous</a>

</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
     <h2>Title 3</h2>

    <p>content here</p> <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="1">Previous</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs-2, #tabs-3 {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.mover').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + '(' + $('#tabs-' + (+$(this).attr('rel')+1)).find('h2').text() + ')');
});
$('.mover').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('div').hide();
    $('#tabs-' + (+$this.attr('rel')+1)).show();
});
```